# Youtube API: Channel Statistics viewCount not updating

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am requesting channel statistics via Youtube API v3 (subscriberCount, videoCount and viewCount). While this works well for the subscriberCount, I get the same value for viewCount for more than one day now (even for channels with more than a million subscribers). What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using the [YouTube-Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/)?

Comment: I am looking for data of third party channels. This does not  work with the YouTube Analytics API.

Comment: Today, I've written a script that checks every day the statistics data of 300 Youtube channels for changes. I hope I can find an answer this way.

Comment: Try in the https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it setting `statistics` in **part** field and set your `id` channel. Execute with authentication and you will get the correct answer for API directly.